# How i get HTML Tag in Angular4? WievChild doesn't provide undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have to make a little game where the user can draw to HTML canvas with angular.

```
<canvas id="canvas" (click)="drawing(this)"></canvas>
```

This is my canvas tag.

```
import {
Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pairwise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draw',
  template: '<canvas id="canvas" (click)="drawing(this)"></canvas>',
  templateUrl: './draw.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draw.component.css']
})

export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {
  // a reference to the canvas element from our template
  @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;

  // setting a width and height for the canvas
  @Input() public width = 400;
  @Input() public height = 400;

  private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;  


  constructor() {
    console.log(this.canvas);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    // get the context
    const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

    // set the width and height
    canvasEl.width = this.width;
    canvasEl.height = this.height;
```

This is in my HTML component. I found on the internet that ViewChild thing, but I don't understand how it works. Is there any other way to get the HTML tag in angular without DOM and jquery?

Comment: ElementRef seems wrong. It should be HTMLFormElement in my opinion

Comment: @ViewChild is used, so that in the reminder of ur code, u can use `this.canvas`  to refer to it. @ViewChild can also be used with forms like this: `@ViewChild('f') signupform: NgForm ` and now be can access this.signupform everywhere in .ts file (there has to be corresponding html changes as well i.e. #f on the form tag like this `<form (ngSubmit) = "mySubmit()" #f=ngForm>`